# How can I have the old comments moderation panel i Gutemberg?

Tags: comments, block-editor, moderation

In the old days was possible to moderate the comments from the post (or page) edit side, but it was removed when Gutenberg become the default. I know I can still use it if I use the classic editor, but I don't want to use it, I like Gutenberg and now it is my default post/page editor.

But I wonder, how could I have that feature in Gutenberg? I know I can add a metabox or panel, but...witch hook or action should I use to show the comment moderation tool there?

Thanks in advantage